# Print pixel band value for a point to the console in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to display the pixel value of Landsat B4 reflectance for a specific image date and coordinate. The following code shows how I select the pixel of interest. How do I extract the value and display it to the console?

```
// The pixel's coordinate       
var lng = -91.2363;
var lat = 30.0919;
var r = ee.Geometry.Point(lng, lat); // r is the pixel of interest

// Load Landsat 7 imagery and filter it
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2004-05-14','2004-05-15') // the date, on 14th May, 2004
  .filterBounds(r);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduceRegion` for that. That can be applied on images.

```
// get one example image and its band asked
var image = collection.first();
// print pixel value of B4 in the console
var pixelInfo = image.reduceRegion({
  geometry: r,
  scale: 30, // nominal sclae landsat
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
});
print(pixelInfo.get('B4'))
```

As an example, and proably more useful, plot a chart of the band vlaues over time (input is an image collection)

```
// or for example plot a chart of the imagecollection B4 band
print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection.select('B4'), r, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30))
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f7ed429184f6d364cd56151cbdbd672)